# On bounds for the quantity $n^2 / D(n^2)$ when $q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $q$ and $k > 1$

Tags: number-theory, upper-lower-bounds, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions, perfect-numbers

Let $N = q^k n^2$ be an [odd perfect number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number#Odd_perfect_numbers) given in Eulerian form (i.e. $q$ is the special/Euler prime satisfying $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q,n)=1$).

In this post, I would like to compute the general expression for the quantity
$$\frac{n^2}{D(n^2)}$$
where $D(x) = 2x - \sigma(x)$ is the *deficiency* of $x$.  (Here, $\sigma(x)=\sigma_1(x)$ is the classical sum of divisors of $x$.)  I would also like to derive bounds for the said quantity, which are hopefully sharp.

It is known that, for an odd perfect number $N = q^k n^2$ given in Eulerian form, we have
$$\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q^k}=\frac{2n^2}{\sigma(q^k)}=\frac{D(n^2)}{s(q^k)}=\frac{2s(n^2)}{D(q^k)},$$
where $s(x)=\sigma(x)-x$ is the *aliquot sum* of $x$.

We obtain, immediately from the middle equation, the equality
$$\frac{n^2}{D(n^2)}=\frac{\sigma(q^k)}{2s(q^k)}.$$

This quantity is an integer if and only if $k=1$ i.e. when the RHS is $(q+1)/2$.  Here I am interested in deriving bounds for this quantity when $k>1$.

We rewrite the RHS as follows:
$$\dfrac{\sigma(q^k)/q^k}{2(s(q^k)/q^k)} = \frac{I(q^k)}{2(I(q^k) - 1)},$$
where $I(x)=\sigma(x)/x$ is the *abundancy index* of $x$.
Now, use the following bounds (which hold since $k>1$ and $k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ imply that $k \geq 5$):
$$I(q^5) \leq I(q^k) < \frac{q}{q-1}.$$
This gives
$$\dfrac{I(q^5)}{2\bigg(\dfrac{q}{q-1} - 1\bigg)} < \frac{n^2}{D(n^2)}=\frac{I(q^k)}{2(I(q^k) - 1)} < \dfrac{\dfrac{q}{q-1}}{2(I(q^5) - 1)}.$$
The **LHS** and **RHS** of the last inequality then simplifies to
$$\text{LHS} = \dfrac{I(q^5)}{2\bigg(\dfrac{q}{q-1} - 1\bigg)} = \frac{q}{2} - \frac{1}{2q^5}$$
while
$$\text{RHS} = \dfrac{\dfrac{q}{q-1}}{2(I(q^5) - 1)} = \frac{q^6}{2(q^5 - 1)}.$$

The function
$$f_1(q) = \frac{q}{2} - \frac{1}{2q^5}$$
is increasing, since its derivative is positive.  Hence
$$f_1(q) \geq f_1(5) = \frac{7812}{3125}$$ since $q$ is a prime satisfying $q \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ implies that $q \geq 5$.

On the other hand, the function
$$f_2(q) = \frac{q^6}{2(q^5 - 1)}$$
is also increasing, since its derivative is also positive.  Thus, we may rewrite $f_2(q)$ as follows:
$$f_2(q) = \frac{q\cdot{q^5}}{2(q^5 - 1)} = \frac{q(q^5 - 1)}{2(q^5 - 1)} + \frac{q}{2(q^5 - 1)} = \frac{q}{2} + \frac{q}{2(q^5 - 1)}.$$

Consequently, we have the following proposition:

> **PROPOSITION:** If $N = q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with special/Euler prime $q$ and $k > 1$ holds, then we have
> $$\frac{7812}{3125} \leq \frac{q}{2} - \frac{1}{2q^5} < \frac{n^2}{D(n^2)} < \frac{q}{2} + \frac{q}{2(q^5 - 1)}.$$

In particular:
$$k > 1 \implies \Bigg(\bigg(\frac{n^2}{D(n^2)} > \frac{7812}{3125}\bigg) \iff \bigg(\frac{D(n^2)}{n^2} < \frac{3125}{7812}\bigg) \iff \bigg(I(n^2) > 2 - \frac{3125}{7182} = \frac{12499}{7182} \approx 1.59997439836\bigg)\Bigg)$$
which does not improve on the currently known
$$I(n^2) > \frac{8}{5}.$$

Here are my:

> **QUESTIONS:** Can you improve on the bounds for $n^2 / D(n^2)$ (in terms of $q$) when $k>1$?  If it is no longer possible to refine the bounds given here, can you explain/show why?

Comment: I noted that
$$\frac{n^2}{D(n^2)} - \frac{q}{2} = \frac{q^{k+1} - 1}{2(q^k - 1)} - \frac{q}{2} = \frac{q - 1}{2(q^k - 1)} = \frac{1}{2s(q^k)}.$$

Comment: Assume that $k>1$.  Then, as in the OP, we have $k \geq 5$.
This implies that
$$\frac{(q-1)/q^k}{2}< \frac{1}{2s(q^k)} = \frac{(1/q^k)}{2(I(q^k) - 1)} \leq \frac{(1/q^k)}{2(I(q^5) - 1)},$$
since, as before, we have
$$I(q^5) \leq I(q^k) < \frac{q}{q-1}.$$

Comment: Yes. We have $\dfrac{n^2}{D(n^2)}=\dfrac{q^{k+1}-1}{2q^k-2}:=f(k)$ which is decreasing in $k$, so we get $\lim_{k\to\infty}f(k)=\dfrac q2\lt \dfrac{n^2}{D(n^2)}\le \dfrac q2+\dfrac{q-1}{2(q^5-1)}=f(5)$. However, this does not improve $I(n^2)\gt 8/5$.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, @mathlove! Please write that out as an answer so that I can upvote and accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

We have
$$\frac{n^2}{D(n^2)}=\frac{\sigma(q^k)}{2s(q^k)}=\frac{q^{k+1}-1}{2(q-1)\bigg(\dfrac{q^{k+1}-1}{q-1}-q^k\bigg)}=\frac{q^{k+1}-1}{2q^k-2}$$

Let $f(k):=\dfrac{q^{k+1}-1}{2q^k-2}$. Then, we get $f'(k)=-\dfrac{(q-1)q^k\log q}{2(q^k-1)^2}$ which is negative.

Since $f(k)$ is decreasing, we obtain
$$\lim_{k\to\infty}f(k)\lt f(k)\le f(5),$$
i.e.
$$\frac q2\lt \frac{n^2}{D(n^2)}\le \frac q2+\dfrac{q-1}{2(q^5-1)}$$