# A proof (?) for $k = 1 \implies q \neq 5$, if $q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $q$

Tags: solution-verification, conjectures, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions, perfect-numbers

Let $N = q^k n^2$ be an [odd perfect number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number#Odd_perfect_numbers) given in Eulerian form (i.e. $q$ is the special/Euler prime satisfying $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q,n)=1$).

Inspired by mathlove's [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4097939/28816) to this closely related MSE question, I reconsider
$$\frac{n^2}{D(n^2)}=\frac{q^{k+1}-1}{2(q^k - 1)}$$
as
$$f(k):=\frac{q^{k+1}-1}{2(q^k - 1)}$$
and
$$g(q):=\frac{q^{k+1}-1}{2(q^k - 1)},$$
where $D(x)=2x-\sigma(x)$ is the *deficiency* of the positive integer $x$ and $\sigma(x)=\sigma_1(x)$ is the *classical sum of divisors* of $x$.

As noted by mathlove,
$$f'(k) = -\frac{(q-1){q^k}\log(q)}{2(q^k - 1)^2} < 0$$
which means $f(k)$ is a decreasing function of $k$, and this implies that
$$\frac{q}{2} = \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}{f(k)} < f(k) \leq f(1) = \frac{q+1}{2}.$$

Also, I noted that
$$g'(q) = \frac{q^{k-1}(q(q^k - 1) - k(q - 1))}{2(q^k - 1)^2} > 0$$
which means $g(q)$ is an increasing function of $q$, and this implies that
$$\frac{5^{k+1} - 1}{2(5^k - 1)} = g(5) \leq g(q) = f(k) \leq f(1) = \frac{q+1}{2}.$$
We obtain
$$5 + \frac{5}{5^k - 1} = \frac{5^{k+1} - 5}{5^k - 1} + \frac{5}{5^k - 1} \leq q + 1.$$
Suppose that $k=1$.  Then we get
$$5 + \frac{5}{4} \leq q + 1 \implies q \geq 4 + \frac{5}{4} = \frac{21}{4}.$$

Here are my:

> **QUESTIONS:** Is this a *logically valid* proof for the implication $k=1 \implies q > 5$?  If the proof is invalid, would it be possible to mend it so as to produce a *logically valid* proof?

Comment: Even though the original proof was flawed, I noted that: In the inequalities
$$g(5) \leq g(q) = f(k) \leq f(1),$$
if
$$(q = 5) \land (k=1)$$
holds, then we obtain
$$3 = \frac{24}{8} = \frac{5^2 - 1}{2(5 - 1)} = \frac{5^{k+1} - 1}{2(5^k - 1)} = g(5) = g(q) = f(k) = f(1) = \frac{q+1}{2} = \frac{5+1}{2} = 3,$$
which is **TRUE**.  Does this mean that
$$(q = 5) \land (k=1)$$
holds in general?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Blimey!**

Found the error:  The expression for
$$\frac{5^{k+1} - 1}{5^k - 1}$$
should have been
$$\frac{5^{k+1} - 1}{5^k - 1}=\frac{5^{k+1} - 5}{5^k - 1}+\frac{5 - 1}{5^k - 1}=5+\frac{4}{5^k - 1}.$$