# On the quantity $I(q^k) + I(n^2)$ considered as functions of $q$ and $k$, when $q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $q$

Tags: number-theory, upper-lower-bounds, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions, perfect-numbers

Hereinafter, let $N = q^k n^2$ be an [odd perfect number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number#Odd_perfect_numbers) with special/Euler prime $q$ satisfying $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q,n)=1$.

Denote the *abundancy index* of the positive integer $x$ by $I(x)=\sigma(x)/x$, where $\sigma(x)=\sigma_1(x)$ is the *classical sum of divisors* of $x$.  Note that, since $N = q^k n^2$ is perfect and $\gcd(q,n)=1$, then we have
$$2=I(N)=I(q^k n^2)=I(q^k)I(n^2).$$

Inspired by the approach in this [MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4097998), I now consider
$$f(k)=g(q):=I(q^k)+I(n^2)=I(q^k)+\frac{2}{I(q^k)}=\bigg(\frac{q^{k+1} - 1}{q^k (q - 1)}\bigg) + \bigg(\frac{2q^k (q - 1)}{q^{k+1} - 1}\bigg)=\frac{3q^{2k+2} - 4q^{2k+1} + 2q^{2k} - 2q^{k+1} + 1}{q^k (q - 1)(q^{k+1} - 1)}.$$

Note that
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial k}{f(k)}=-\log(q)\Bigg[\dfrac{(((q-4)q + 2)q^k + 2q)q^k - 1}{{q^k}(q - 1)(q^{k+1} - 1)^2}\Bigg] < 0$$
([WolframAlpha computational verification is here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Differentiate%20%28%28q%5E%28k%2B1%29%20-%201%29%2F%28q%5Ek%20%28q%20-%201%29%29%29%20%2B%20%28%282q%5Ek%20%28q%20-%201%29%29%2F%28q%5E%28k%2B1%29%20-%201%29%29%20with%20respect%20to%20k))
and that
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial q}{g(q)}=\dfrac{\bigg(q(q^k - 1) - k(q - 1)\bigg)\Bigg(q^k \bigg(((q-4)q + 2)q^k + 2q\bigg) - 1\Bigg)}{{q^{k+1}}(q - 1)^2 (q^{k+1} - 1)^2} > 0$$
([WolframAlpha computational verification is here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Differentiate%20%28%28q%5E%28k%2B1%29%20-%201%29%2F%28q%5Ek%20%28q%20-%201%29%29%29%20%2B%20%28%282q%5Ek%20%28q%20-%201%29%29%2F%28q%5E%28k%2B1%29%20-%201%29%29%20with%20respect%20to%20q)).

In particular, this means that
$$g(5) \leq  g(q) = f(k) \leq f(1)$$
since $g(q)$ is increasing while $f(k)$ is decreasing.

But we have
$$g(5) = \frac{57 \times {5^{2k}} - 2 \times {5^{k+1}} + 1}{4 \times {5^k} (5^{k+1} - 1)}$$
while
$$f(1) = \frac{3q^2 + 2q + 1}{q(q + 1)} = 3 - \bigg(\frac{q - 1}{q(q + 1)}\bigg).$$

Consequently, we obtain
$$\frac{57 \times {5^{2k}} - 2 \times {5^{k+1}} + 1}{4 \times {5^k} (5^{k+1} - 1)} \leq 3 - \bigg(\frac{q - 1}{q(q + 1)}\bigg)$$
which is equivalent to
$$\frac{q - 1}{q(q + 1)} \leq 3 - \Bigg(\frac{57 \times {5^{2k}} - 2 \times {5^{k+1}} + 1}{4 \times {5^k} (5^{k+1} - 1)}\Bigg) = \frac{3 \times {5^{2k}} - 2 \times {5^k} - 1}{4 \times {5^k} (5^{k+1} - 1)},$$
which, in turn, is equivalent to
$$\frac{4 \times {5^k} (5^{k+1} - 1)}{3 \times {5^{2k}} - 2 \times {5^k} - 1} \leq \frac{q(q+1)}{q-1} = \frac{q(q-1)}{q-1}+\frac{2q}{q-1}=q+\frac{2q}{q-1}=q+\frac{2(q-1)}{q-1}+\frac{2}{q-1}=(q+2)+\frac{2}{q-1}.$$
But [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Partial%20fraction%20decomposition%20of%20%28%284%285%5Ek%29%285%5E%28k%2B1%29%20-%201%29%29%2F%283%285%5E%282k%29%29%20-%202%285%5Ek%29%20-%201%29%29) says that the partial fraction decomposition of
$$\frac{4 \times {5^k} (5^{k+1} - 1)}{3 \times {5^{2k}} - 2 \times {5^k} - 1}$$
is
$$\frac{4 \times {5^k} (5^{k+1} - 1)}{3 \times {5^{2k}} - 2 \times {5^k} - 1} = \frac{20}{3} + \frac{4}{5^k - 1} - \frac{8}{3\bigg(3 \times {5^k} + 1\bigg)},$$
and that
$$\frac{4}{5^k - 1} - \frac{8}{3\bigg(3 \times {5^k} + 1\bigg)} > 0$$
for $k \geq 1$.

Thus, we have the series of numerical inequalities
$$\frac{20}{3} < \frac{4 \times {5^k} (5^{k+1} - 1)}{3 \times {5^{2k}} - 2 \times {5^k} - 1} \leq \frac{q(q+1)}{q-1} = (q+2) + \frac{2}{q-1} \leq (q+2) + \frac{2}{4} = (q+2) + \frac{1}{2} = q + \frac{5}{2}$$
$$\implies 4.1\overline{666} = \frac{25}{6} = \frac{40 - 15}{6} = \frac{20}{3} - \frac{5}{2} < q \implies q \geq 5.$$

Here are my:

> **QUESTIONS:** Can we improve on the starting-point inequality
> $$g(5) \leq g(q) = f(k) \leq f(1),$$
> to hopefully produce a *nontrivial lower bound* for $q$?  If this is not possible, can you explain/show why?

Answer (score 1):

**Too long to comment:**

From the inequality
$$\frac{q-1}{q(q+1)} \leq \frac{{3 \times 5^{2k}} - {2 \times {5^k}} - 1}{4 \times {5^k}(5^{k+1} - 1)},$$
since
$$h(k) := \frac{{3 \times 5^{2k}} - {2 \times {5^k}} - 1}{4 \times {5^k}(5^{k+1} - 1)}$$
is increasing for $k \geq 1$ (see [this WolframAlpha computational verification](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=D%5B%283%285%5E%282k%29%29+-+2%285%5Ek%29+-+1%29%2F%284%285%5Ek%29%285%5E%28k%2B1%29+-+1%29%29%2Ck%5D+%3E+0) for more details), then we have
$$\frac{q-1}{q(q+1)} < \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}{h(k)} = \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}{\Bigg(\frac{{3 \times 5^{2k}} - {2 \times {5^k}} - 1}{4 \times {5^k}(5^{k+1} - 1)}\Bigg)} = \frac{3}{20},$$
which implies that
$$\frac{57}{20} = 3 - \frac{3}{20} < 3 - \Bigg(\frac{q-1}{q(q+1)}\Bigg) = \frac{3q^2 + 2q + 1}{q(q + 1)} = \frac{q + 1}{q} + \frac{2q}{q + 1}.$$

But since $q$ is the special prime satisfying $q \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, then $q \geq 5$, which implies that
$$I(q) = \frac{q+1}{q} = 1 + \frac{1}{q} \leq \frac{6}{5}$$
$$I(n^2) = \frac{2}{I(q)} = \frac{2q}{q+1} \geq \frac{5}{3}.$$
Note that
$$I(q) \leq \frac{6}{5} < \frac{5}{3} \leq I(n^2).$$

Consider the *nonpositive product*
$$\Bigg(I(q) - \frac{6}{5}\Bigg)\Bigg(I(n^2) - \frac{6}{5}\Bigg) \leq 0.$$
We obtain
$$I(q)I(n^2) + \bigg(\frac{6}{5}\bigg)^2 \leq \frac{6}{5}\Bigg(I(q) + I(n^2)\Bigg),$$
from which we get
$$\frac{43}{15} = \frac{5}{3} + \frac{6}{5} = \frac{5}{6}\Bigg(2 + \bigg(\frac{6}{5}\bigg)^2\Bigg) \leq I(q) + I(n^2) = \frac{q+1}{q} + \frac{2q}{q+1}.$$

**Notice that
$$\frac{43}{15} > \frac{57}{20},$$
and that
$$I(q) + I(n^2) > \frac{57}{20}$$
is *trivial* compared to
$$I(q^k) + I(n^2) = I(q) + I(n^2) \geq \frac{43}{15},$$
where we note that the latter bound holds under the assumption $k=1$.**