# On the quantity $I(q^k) + I(n^2)$ considered as functions of $q$ and $k$, when $q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $q$ - Part II

Tags: number-theory, upper-lower-bounds, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions, perfect-numbers

Hereinafter, let $N = q^k n^2$ be an [odd perfect number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number#Odd_perfect_numbers) with special/Euler prime $q$ satisfying $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q,n)=1$.

Denote the *abundancy index* of the positive integer $x$ by $I(x)=\sigma(x)/x$, where $\sigma(x)=\sigma_1(x)$ is the *classical sum of divisors* of $x$.  Note that, since $N = q^k n^2$ is perfect and $\gcd(q,n)=1$, then we have
$$2=I(N)=I(q^k n^2)=I(q^k)I(n^2).$$

Inspired by the approach in this [MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4104493), I now consider
$$f(k)=g(q):=I(q^k)+I(n^2)=I(q^k)+\frac{2}{I(q^k)}=\bigg(\frac{q^{k+1} - 1}{q^k (q - 1)}\bigg) + \bigg(\frac{2q^k (q - 1)}{q^{k+1} - 1}\bigg)=\frac{3q^{2k+2} - 4q^{2k+1} + 2q^{2k} - 2q^{k+1} + 1}{q^k (q - 1)(q^{k+1} - 1)}.$$

Note that
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial k}{f(k)}=-\log(q)\Bigg[\dfrac{(((q-4)q + 2)q^k + 2q)q^k - 1}{{q^k}(q - 1)(q^{k+1} - 1)^2}\Bigg] < 0$$
([WolframAlpha computational verification is here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Differentiate%20%28%28q%5E%28k%2B1%29%20-%201%29%2F%28q%5Ek%20%28q%20-%201%29%29%29%20%2B%20%28%282q%5Ek%20%28q%20-%201%29%29%2F%28q%5E%28k%2B1%29%20-%201%29%29%20with%20respect%20to%20k))
and that
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial q}{g(q)}=\dfrac{\bigg(q(q^k - 1) - k(q - 1)\bigg)\Bigg(q^k \bigg(((q-4)q + 2)q^k + 2q\bigg) - 1\Bigg)}{{q^{k+1}}(q - 1)^2 (q^{k+1} - 1)^2} > 0$$
([WolframAlpha computational verification is here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Differentiate%20%28%28q%5E%28k%2B1%29%20-%201%29%2F%28q%5Ek%20%28q%20-%201%29%29%29%20%2B%20%28%282q%5Ek%20%28q%20-%201%29%29%2F%28q%5E%28k%2B1%29%20-%201%29%29%20with%20respect%20to%20q)).

In particular, this means that
$$g(5) \leqslant  g(q) = f(k) \leqslant f(1)$$
since $g(q)$ is increasing while $f(k)$ is decreasing.

But we have
$$g(5) = \frac{57 \times {5^{2k}} - 2 \times {5^{k+1}} + 1}{4 \times {5^k} (5^{k+1} - 1)}$$
while
$$f(1) = \frac{3q^2 + 2q + 1}{q(q + 1)} = 3 - \bigg(\frac{q - 1}{q(q + 1)}\bigg).$$

Consequently, we obtain
$$\frac{57 \times {5^{2k}} - 2 \times {5^{k+1}} + 1}{4 \times {5^k} (5^{k+1} - 1)} \leqslant 3 - \bigg(\frac{q - 1}{q(q + 1)}\bigg)$$
which is equivalent to
$$\frac{q - 1}{q(q + 1)} \leqslant 3 - \Bigg(\frac{57 \times {5^{2k}} - 2 \times {5^{k+1}} + 1}{4 \times {5^k} (5^{k+1} - 1)}\Bigg) = \frac{3 \times {5^{2k}} - 2 \times {5^k} - 1}{4 \times {5^k} (5^{k+1} - 1)},$$
which, in turn, is equivalent to
$$(q-1)\bigg(4 \times {5^k} (5^{k+1} - 1)\bigg) \leqslant q(q+1)\bigg(3 \times {5^{2k}} - 2 \times {5^k} - 1\bigg).$$

Setting
$$N(k) := 3 \times {5^{2k}} - 2 \times {5^k} - 1$$
and
$$D(k) := 4 \times {5^k} (5^{k+1} - 1)$$
gives
$$(q-1)D(k) \leqslant q(q+1)N(k).$$

Note that
$$D'(k) = 4 \times {5^k} (2 \times 5^{k+1} - 1) \log(5) > 0$$
and
$$N'(k) = 2 \times {5^k} (3 \times 5^{k} - 1) \log(5) > 0$$
which means that $D(k)$ and $N(k)$ are *increasing functions* of $k$.  In particular, we have the lower bounds
$$D(k) \geqslant D(1) = 480 > 0,$$
and
$$N(k) \geqslant N(1) = 64 > 0.$$

My problem now is how to extract a closed form for a bound on $q$ in terms of $5$ and $k$.

**MY ATTEMPT**

Solving the inequality
$$(q-1)D(k) \leqslant q(q+1)N(k)$$
for $q$, and noting that $D(k)$ and $N(k)$ are both positive for all $k \geqslant 1$, we obtain
$$qD(k) - D(k) \leqslant q^2 N(k) + qN(k)$$
$$q^2 N(k) + q(N(k) - D(k)) + D(k) \geqslant 0$$

But we have
$$N(k) - D(k) = 2 \times {5^k} - 17 \times {5^{2k}} - 1 < 0.$$

We require that the discriminant
$$d = (N(k) - D(k))^2 - 4N(k)D(k) \geqslant 0$$
in order for the quadratic inequality above to have solutions.

However, [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=FullSimplify%5B%282%285%5Ek%29%20-%2017%285%5E%282k%29%29%20-%201%29%5E2%20-%204%28%283%285%5E%282k%29%29%20-%202%285%5Ek%29%20-%201%29%284%285%5Ek%29%285%5E%28k%2B1%29%20-%201%29%29%29%5D) simplifies $d$ to be
$$d = \bigg(7 \times {5^{2k}} + 2 \times {5^{k+1}} - 1\bigg)^2,$$
which is indeed nonnegative.  Hence, we obtain the following critical points for the quadratic inequality above:

$$q_1 := \frac{\bigg(17 \times {5^{2k}} - 2 \times {5^k} + 1\bigg) - \bigg(7 \times {5^{2k}} + 2 \times {5^{k+1}} - 1\bigg)}{2\bigg(3 \times {5^{2k}} - 2 \times {5^k} - 1\bigg)} = \frac{10 \times {5^{2k}} - 12 \times {5^k} + 2}{2\bigg(3 \times {5^{2k}} - 2 \times {5^k} - 1\bigg)}$$
and
$$q_2 := \frac{\bigg(17 \times {5^{2k}} - 2 \times {5^k} + 1\bigg) + \bigg(7 \times {5^{2k}} + 2 \times {5^{k+1}} - 1\bigg)}{2\bigg(3 \times {5^{2k}} - 2 \times {5^k} - 1\bigg)} = \frac{24 \times {5^{2k}} + 8 \times {5^k}}{2\bigg(3 \times {5^{2k}} - 2 \times {5^k} - 1\bigg)}.$$
(Note that $q_1 < q_2$.)

We obtain the solutions
$$\bigg(q \leqslant q_1\bigg) \lor \bigg(q \geqslant q_2\bigg).$$
Of these, the solutions for
$$q \leqslant q_1$$
are **extraneous**, since $q$ being the special prime means that $q \geq 5$.

Letting
$$h(k) := q_2 = \frac{24 \times {5^{2k}} + 8 \times {5^k}}{2\bigg(3 \times {5^{2k}} - 2 \times {5^k} - 1\bigg)}$$
and differentiating with respect to $k$, we get
$$h'(k) = -\frac{\bigg(4 \times {5^k}\bigg)\log(5)}{(5^k - 1)^2} < 0$$
which means that $h(k)$ is *decreasing*.

Hence, we obtain
$$q \geqslant q_2 = h(k) \geqslant \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}{h(k)} = \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}\Bigg(\frac{24 \times {5^{2k}} + 8 \times {5^k}}{2(3 \times {5^{2k}} - 2 \times {5^k} - 1)}\Bigg) = 4,$$
which *does not improve* on the known lower bound $q \geqslant 5$.

Here are my questions:

> > **INQUIRIES**

> **(1)** Is the proof above for $q \geqslant 4$ logically sound?

> **(2)** If the answer to *Question* **(1)** is *NO*, how can the proof be mended so as to produce a valid result?

> **(3)** Can we do better than $q \geqslant 4$?

**Added on January 11, 2022 - 1:36 PM Manila time**

Note that we appear to have obtained the final resulting inequality
$$q \geqslant \frac{24 \times {5^{2k}} + 8 \times {5^k}}{2(3 \times {5^{2k}} - 2 \times {5^k} - 1)} \geqslant 4.$$

This inequality is equivalent to the lower bound
$$k \geqslant \log_{5}\Bigg(\frac{q}{q-4}\Bigg) \geqslant 0,$$
so that we have the implications
$$k = 1 \implies q \geqslant 5$$
and
$$q = 5 \implies k \geqslant 1,$$
**both** of which are *trivial*.

Comment: For (1), I think that the answer is yes. For (3), I think that what you have done suggests that using only $g(5) \leqslant f(1)$, $q\geqslant q_2\gt 4$ is the best result that you can get. In other words, I think that using only $g(5) \leqslant f(1)$, you cannot get any better result than $q\geqslant q_2\gt 4$. This does not mean that you cannot get any better result than $q\geqslant q_2\gt 4$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and attention, @mathlove!  I invite you to write out your last comment as an actual answer (with, perhaps, an explanation for why $q_2 \neq 4$), so that I can upvote and then accept.  =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On OP's request, I am converting my comment into an answer.

For (1), I think that the answer is yes.

For (3), I think that what you have done suggests that using only $g(5)\leqslant f(1)$, $q\geqslant q_2\gt 4$ is the best result that you can get. In other words, I think that using only $g(5)\leqslant f(1)$, you cannot get any better result than $q\geqslant q_2\gt 4$. This does not mean that you cannot get any better result than $q\geqslant q_2\gt 4$.

---

An explanation for why $q_2\not=4$.

Suppose that there is $k$ such that $q_2=4$. Then,
$$\begin{align}\frac{12 \times {5^{2k}} + 4 \times {5^k}}{3 \times {5^{2k}} - 2 \times {5^k} - 1}=4&\implies 12 \times {5^{2k}} + 4 \times {5^k}=12\times {5^{2k}} - 8 \times {5^k} - 4\\\\&\implies  3 \times {5^k}= - 1\end{align}$$
which is impossible.