# Can this inequality be solved for $q$ in terms of $n$ (or the other way around), if $q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $q$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, inequality, logarithms, perfect-numbers

Let $q^k n^2$ be an odd perfect number with special prime $q$ satisfying $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q,n)=1$.

The following general inequality relating $k$ and $q$ is proved in this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4353765):
$$k \geq \log_{5}{\bigg(\frac{q}{q-4}\bigg)} \tag{1}.$$

On the other hand, Dris proved in 2012 (see [Journal of Integer Sequences](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL15/Dris/dris8.html)) the inequality
$$q^k < \frac{2n^2}{3}$$
which implies that
$$k < \log_{q} 2 - \log_{q} 3 + 2\log_{q} n. \tag{2}$$

Together, Inequalities **(1)** and **(2)** imply that
$$\log_{5} q - \log_{5} (q - 4) \leq k < \log_{q} 2 - \log_{q} 3 + 2\log_{q} n,$$
so that we have
$$\log_{5} q - \log_{5} (q - 4) < \log_{q} 2 - \log_{q} 3 + 2\log_{q} n. \tag{3}$$

Here is my:

> **QUESTION:** Can Inequality **(3)** be solved for $q$ in terms of $n$ (or the other way around), if $q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $q$?  If **YES**, can you show how?  If **NO**, can you explain why?

**MY ATTEMPT**

I tried to ask [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Solve+log_5+%28q%2F%28q+-+4%29%29+%3C+log_q+%282%29+-+log_q+%283%29+%2B+2+log_q+%28n%29+for+log%28q%29) for the solutions of Inequality **(3)** to $\log q$ and did also try to ask [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Solve+log_5+%28q%2F%28q+-+4%29%29+%3C+log_q+%282%29+-+log_q+%283%29+%2B+2+log_q+%28n%29+for+log%28n%29) for the solutions of Inequality **(3)** to $\log n$, but I do not know how to interpret the results.

In particular, solving for $\log n$ from Inequality **(3)**, WolframAlpha is giving me
$$\Bigg(\log n > \frac{\log(q)\log\bigg(\frac{q}{q-4}\bigg) - (\log(2) - \log(3))\log(5)}{2\log(5)}\Bigg) \land \Bigg(\log\bigg(\frac{q}{q-4}\bigg) \in \mathbb{R}\Bigg) \land \Bigg(\log(q) > 0\Bigg),$$
where we know that the second and third conditions are always satisfied since $q$ being the special prime implies that $q \geq 5$.

**Alas, this is where I get stuck!**

Comment: Does the first condition obtained in **MY ATTEMPT** imply $q < n$?

Comment: This [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Reduce%5Blog%28n%29+%3E+%28log%28q%29log%28q%2F%28q+-+4%29%29+-+%28log%282%29+-+log%283%29%29log%285%29%29%2F%282log%285%29%29%2CIntegers%5D) **Reduce** computation for the first condition outputs
$$n = \frac{937}{10} \text{ and } q = \frac{209}{5},$$
as a *solution over the reals*, so I am all the more *confused*!